# Wordpress authentication from javascript client

Tags: javascript, wordpress, authentication

I have some custom javascript for which i want my user to authenticate. Instead of designing my own authentication scheme with data-base and custom server-side code, i'd like to use the existing Wordpress authentication that is already running on my server. Basically the user would go to my website, authenticate with wordpress and then access the page serving my javascript app. In this application i want to check if the user is logged in (how to get this information from wordpress) and then perform some tasks based on the user credentials. I gave a quick look at existing Wordpress plugins and found the JSON REST API but i don't see how to perform the given scenario.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wordpress to authenticate, well you're hosting a Wordpress site. The concept of switching back and forth is unusual. When a remote web browser sends a request that ends up being authenticated as a Wordpress user, the server then spits back the results instantly. The user doesn't normally stay "logged in" in any sense that another application could poll. A user being logged in, normally means their password and user name are stored as a cookie on their browser. The system authenticates them every time they request a page. So if Wordpress doesn't run on the specific request your talking about, your other application couldn't know if the user was logged in or not.

Get Wordpress running, then figure out a way to put your javascript inside wordpress. For instance as a post, or a page template.

Comment: i have Wordpress running on my website. The thing is that i would like my user to use a javascript application with their login/pass used to authenticate in wordpress (and vanilla forum). From what i undertand, there is no way to check that a user is registered (on wordpres) outside wordpress ?

Comment: Still trying to be precise with the terminology. Wordpress is a PHP program that runs when a person sends an HTTP request to a webserver. So Wordpress isn't "running" on a site in any sense unless a person sends a HTTP request through a browser, then the request typically tak

Comment: es less than a second before a response is sent the the browser. "REGISTERED" usually means that a user has been assigned a user ID, and has an account on a site. "LOGGED IN", in Wordpress, means that the user has a cookie in their browser than has a valid password and username. So you could, from another app, for instance send an AJAX request to a Wordpress site and get information about users. You could generally tell if a user was registered, you generally could not tell if a user was logged in.

Comment: Good advice: Don't try to re-invent the wheel. If you don't know how to make a wheel, copy someone else.